# SwiftUI Animation Slide In and Out

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have a View that will display over another View. The view animation slides in from the right perfectly, but when I click on the Close button, the view disappears without the desired animation of sliding back to the right before disappearing.

I have tried using .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0), but then the View fades in and out, I need it to slide in and out. Other variations have not produced the desired results.

What am I doing wrong? Any guidance, even a duplicate solution (that I could not find) would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct NotificationView<parentView>: View where parentView: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    let parentView: () -> parentView

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                self.parentView()
                    
                if(self.isShowing == true){
                    VStack {
                        Text("This is a test view\n")
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isShowing.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Close")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
//                    .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
                    .transition(.move(edge: self.isShowing ? .trailing : .leading))
                    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move conditional part into container and add animation to container, so it will animate content, like

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            self.parentView()
                
          VStack {                       // << here !!
            if(self.isShowing == true){
                VStack {
                    Text("This is a test view\n")
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isShowing.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Close")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                .transition(.move(edge: self.isShowing ? .trailing : .leading))
            }
          }.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))    // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you, I have been working on this for hours, thanks again!